# Specify marker color to come from colormap in @pre marker code

Tags: pgfplots

I'm making a 3D scatter plot of point data (markers only). I want the marker size dependent on one metadata column in my table, and the marker color dependent on another metadata column - I've managed to do this and it works well, using `visualization depends on` and `scatter/@pre marker code/.append style`.

I now want to make the marker type conditional on one of the meta values, such that if the meta value is 0, I have marker type A, and otherwise, I have marker type B. I found how to do this in the pgfplots manual (pg. 111 in version 2015/01/31). This method uses `scatter/@pre marker code/.code`, which overrides all the normal marker styles. I managed to put the marker size command that I had in `scatter/@pre marker code/.append style` into this command, so the size is mapped correctly, but it remains to map the color to the colormap the way I had it originally for marker type B.

I guess what I'm looking for is the command to say `fill={take from colormap}` within the following context:

`\def\markopts{fill={take from colormap}}`

My whole addplot command looked like this originally (no marker style evaluation):

```
\addplot3[scatter,mark=cube*,only marks,scatter src=explicit,z buffer=sort,
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{m}\as\wtwo,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={%
        /tikz/mark size=0.01+\wtwo/3000,
    }
]
table[x=x,y=y,z=z,meta=density]{Plots/datafilename.txt}
;
```

With the version including the marker type selection, I had the following:

```
\addplot3[scatter,mark=cube*,only marks,scatter src=explicit,z buffer=sort,
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{m}\as\wtwo,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
        \ifdim\wtwo pt<300pt
            \def\markopts{mark=+,mark size=1pt}%
        \else
            \def\markopts{mark=cube*,mark size=0.01+\wtwo/3000}%
        \fi
        \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
    },%
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
        \endscope
    },%
]
table[x=x,y=y,z=z,meta=density]{Plots/datafilename.txt}
;
```

Comment: Hi ope, welcome to the site! Could you turn your code snippet into a complete but minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`), including some dummy data, to make it easier to start working on a solution?

Comment: The standard scatter styles all provide a starred version, i.e. something like  `scatter/use mapped color*`. This key might actually do what you want: it uses `\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` in order to make `fill=mapped color` a valid statement. In addition, it uses `scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={}` and `scatter/@post marker code/.prefix code={}` in order to _append_ its functionality to an existing style selection.

Comment: Did the trick from Christian solve your problem or do you need further assistance. If so, please follow Jake's comment. Thanks.